# does retry_on get excuted first before discard_on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Context:

I have a job that catch some errors with these configuration

```ruby
class CheckBankStatusJob < BaseJob
  discard_on(ConnectionErrors::Error) do
   Logger.new(STDOUT).warn("Connection Error!")
  end

  retry_on(
   BankError::NoResponseData,
   StandardError,
   wait: 5.seconds,
  )
end
```

`ConnectionErrors` inherit from `StandardError`

`BankError::NoResponseData` inherit from `StandardError`

i want to test the `discard_on` event in rspec

```ruby
it "logs down when RemoteErrors::Error" do
 allow_any_instance_of(described_class).to receive(:perform).and_raise(ConnectionErrors::Error)
 expect_any_instance_of(Logger).to receive(:warn).with("Connection Error!")
 described_class.perform_now
end
```

it never go to `discard_on` block, instead it goes to `retry_on` block.

errors

```
Failure/Error:
expected: 1 time with arguments: xxx
received: 0 times
```

Does `retry_on` get executed first? or it is because the `ConnectionErrors` get inherited from `StandardError`?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to replace "perform" with "perform_now" to raise ConnectionErrors::Error

```
allow_any_instance_of(described_class).to receive(:perform_now).and_raise(ConnectionErrors::Error)
```

Comment: That could work...

Comment: it raises the error yes, but it does not go to discard_on block. it should be running the discard_on block in my understanding, but somehow it does not go there

Comment: I think it could be because you are checking "warn", can you raise "error" logger and see if it works? Because maybe it is because of logger level setting it is skipping warn logs? Or you can check something else other than logger inside to be sure that discard_on is called or not. Do you have anything set in test.rb log_level? If not try to set it to to ensure warn logs are not skipped. Valid log_levels are debug, info, warn, error